# KVM : virtio better?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt, virtio

I found many articles about changing to *virtio*, but I don't know the reason.

Does *virtio* have higher performance?

[image: virtio]

Comment: https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Virtio#:~:text=So%2Dcalled%20%22full%20virtualization%22,is%20both%20complicated%20and%20inefficient.

Comment: @roaima thank you,so virtio is recommend.